# ComplexListPlot not complete

Tags: plotting, complex

This code creates three complex lists. The third list is the `Union` of the other two. There are three plots. When applying `ComplexListPlot` to all three lists I would expect the third plot to be the first two plots combined. But no! Why? What am I missing?

```
z = Table[{x, I*y}, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -2, 0}]
s = z^3
g = Union[z, s]
ComplexListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full] & @@ z
ComplexListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full] & @@ s
ComplexListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full] & @@ g
```

[image: First plot]

[image: Second Plot]

[image: Third Plot]

So I expected to add the first and second plot. But The second plot equals the third plot. `ComplexListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full] & @@ g[[3;;4]]` gives partly the right picture. Very strange! I use Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: try `ComplexListPlot[z[[1]], Joined->True]`, 
`ComplexListPlot[s[[1]], Joined->True]` and 
`ComplexListPlot[Join[z[[1]],s[[1]]], Joined->True]`

Comment: hint: consider `z1 = {u, v, w}; s1 = {a, b, c}; g1 = Union[z1, s1];` and compare
`# & @@ z1`  and `# & @@ s1` and `# & @@ g1` (versus, say `#2 & @@ z1`  and `#2 & @@ s1` and `#2 & @@ g1`), Similarly, for an arbitrary function `foo`,  inspect `foo[# ]& @@ z1`  and `foo[# ]& @@ s1` and `foo[# ]& @@ g1` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the output from `Table`. E.g. `z`

```
{{{-2, -2 I}, {-2, -I}, {-2, 0}}, {{-1, -2 I}, {-1, -I}, {-1, 0}}, {{0, -2 I}, {0, -I}, {0, 0}}}
```

This is a list of 3 elements. Each element is a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a real and an imaginary number.

I assume that you wanted to create a list of complex numbers and to plot them. To do so, you must write:

```
z = Flatten[Table[{x + I*y}, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -2, 0}], 1]
```

Further, `ComplexListPlot` takes one argument and options. But when you write

```
ComplexListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full] & @@ z
```

All the elements of z are given as arguments to ``ComplexListPlot`. The first is then treated as data, the rest as options. Therefore, you should write something like:

```
z = Flatten[Table[{x + I*y}, {x, -2, 0}, {y, -2, 0}], 1]
s = z^3
g = Union[z, s]
ComplexListPlot[z]
ComplexListPlot[s]
ComplexListPlot[g]
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, obviously my question was ambiguous. I edited my question by adding three outputs for clarification. Any other idea?

Comment: With your input, I only get 2 lines per plot. Could it be a version problem? I have 12.1